# How to use a dynamic value for object's field?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an object SentimentScore as such

```
SentimentScore:
{Mixed: 0.00005830301233800128,
Negative: 0.0011920471442863345,
Neutral: 0.9854754209518433,
Positive: 0.013274261727929115}
```

I want the values based on what I have set in a variable, for eg:

```
var finalSentiment1 = 'Neutral';
var finalSentiment2 = 'Positive';
```

I want to use the variables instead, to find the values of fields of the SentimentScore.

Something like, SentimentScore.finalSentiment1 should give 0.0011920471442863345.

Is it possible without using a conditional statement? If yes, how? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use computed (`[]`) property which will allow you to have an expression to be computed as a property name on an object dynamically:

```js
var SentimentScore = {
  Mixed: 0.00005830301233800128,
  Negative: 0.0011920471442863345,
  Neutral: 0.9854754209518433,
  Positive: 0.013274261727929115
}

var finalSentiment1 = 'Neutral';
var finalSentiment2 = 'Positive';

console.log(SentimentScore[finalSentiment1]);
console.log(SentimentScore[finalSentiment2]);
```